# Is there any educational value into reading the original work of the authors who discovered certain theorems or concepts?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, math-history

I am interested in reading original work of some authors of theorems or concepts in mathematics because I believe that there is also an educational value to this and it might help me understand better those concepts because I can see where and how they came from from the author's minds.

For example I would be really curious into reading the work of Leibnitz and Newton regarding calculus, differentials, and integrals.

Do you think it could help me better understand those concepts?

If yes, can anyone help me to find those original works?

Comment: I have thought about whether, if I were to be transported back in time and allowed with me a limited number of books, I should bring the works that made our world a better place and / or revolutionized our understanding of the world, the universe and ourselves... Or generic undergraduate texts detailing the same theory from a modern perspective. I think the modern textbooks, although not revolutionary to us, is the better option to go with. That being said, the originals might be good insights into the minds of people with the capacity to do what Newton, Darwin and da Vinci has done for us.

Comment: @Arthur Is it possible to download copies of those original works?

Comment: Yes, there is educational value in reading original authors. You will see how the discovery process is not as clean and straightforward as a summary might make it look.

Comment: @Olivier This is what I think also. I am very curious to find more about the original process of discovery and about the authors.

Comment: You may read Newton's original ["Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica"](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/28233) at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org). It is in Latin, which is probably a problem...

Comment: For me the most unfortunate part is that most works of original authors may not be the language you understand (most of the beautiful math is in German, French and Latin). If you can understand these language do go for original works as they are much more interesting than the yellow colored GTM series books from Springer. There is also the minor barrier of old notation but it is generally worthwhile to study original works especially when you have already studied the equivalent GTM texts as part of your studies.

Comment: Laubenbaucher and Pengelley's *Mathematical Expeditions: Chronicles be the Explorers* is an excellent book that uses translated excerpts from original works to quickly develop, motivate, and highlight the most important historical aspects of 5 mathematical fields (Geometry, Set Theory, Analysis, Number Theory, and Algebra). The text is riddled with hundreds of excellent sources and analyses which you might find helpful in your study if you would like to go deeper than the book allows.

Comment: Michael Spivak loves to do this. His Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry series examines some of the original papers. His book Physics for Mathematicians: Mechanics 1 takes a close look at some passages from Newton's Principia.

Answer (score 0):

## Maybe

I found people *saying* that it's useful, but no empirical evidence.

### Example

In their paper [Teaching and Learning Mathematics From Primary Historical Sources](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10511970.2015.1054010), Barnett et al. describe their method of introducing students to topics via historical texts.

### Motivation

From the paper:

> Thus, we are using primary sources not only to introduce mathematics via authentic motivation, but as challenging texts for students actively to “interpret” as a component of creating their own meaningful understanding of modern mathematics. Our tasks for students now therefore often incorporate a more active “read, reflect, respond” paradigm.

### Usefulness

I could not, at first glance, find any empirical analysis of the effectiveness of this approach. They do get positive feedback from their students via a post-course questionnaire, though.

### Access

I am not aware of any specific repository for historical mathematical texts, but I imagine they can be found like most historical texts (e.g. on [archive](https://archive.org/)).

### See also

- One of the authors of the linked paper has a [website](https://web.nmsu.edu/%7Edavidp/history/) on similar
  courses.
- More on the pedagogical [goals](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/historical-projects/Papers/HPM-collected-volume-historical-projects-rev01.pdf) of those courses.
- For ideas of how to find literature without having institutional access,
  see [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63369/literature-searches-in-publications-when-you-have-limited-access-to-journals) and [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68236/how-does-libgen-scihub-affect-researchers-research-and-publishing-process?noredirect=1&lq=1).
- However, since you will be looking for historical texts that should be in the public domain, you can make use of the [gutenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Gutenberg) project and similar projects.
- Honorary mention: A [beautiful](https://www.c82.net/euclid/) online version of The Elements of Euclid.